# DIV won't scroll all the way down

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am back at it again with another question/problem for my cheeky menu.I have finally finished it and functionally it fully worked, until I checked it on my phone.When I expanded all of the the menus, the div will scroll just a few pixels. I think my problem comes from the fact that some elements have `overflow: hidden` and that the body and html height is set to 100%( in another file, which is the index.The code I provide is from the menu file, a separate one). This is my mark-up :

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <img class="logo" alt="Logo" src="pictures\sigla.png"></img>
    <div class="meniu">
        <div class="dropdown-meniu">
            <div id="buton-meniu" class="buton-meniu" onclick="myFunction(this)">
                <div class="bar1"></div>
                <div class="bar2"></div>
                <div class="bar3"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="dropdown-meniu-content" class="dropdown-meniu-content">
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <div id="buton-ferestre" class="buton" onclick="expansiune_ferestre()">Ferestre<div id="arrow-up-ferestre" class="arrow-up"></div></div>
                    <div id="dropdown-ferestre-content" class="dropdown-content">
                        <ul type="none">
                        <li><a class="text">S3000</a></li>
                        <li><a class="text">S8000</a></li>
                        <li><a class="text">S9000</a></li>
                        <li><a class="text">Vitraj</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <div id="buton-usi" class="buton" onclick="expansiune_usi()">Usi<div id="arrow-up-usi" class="arrow-up"></div></div>
                    <div id="dropdown-usi-content" class="dropdown-content">
                        <ul type="none">
                        <span><li><a class="text">Intrare</a></li>
                        <li><a class="text">Siguranta</a></li>
                        <li><a class="text">Garaj</a></li>
                        <li><a class="text">Glisante</a></li></span>
                        <span><li><a class="text">Armonice</a></li></span>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="buton-s">Aerisire</div>
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <div id="buton-sticla" class="buton" onclick="expansiune_sticla()">Sticla<div id="arrow-up-sticla" class="arrow-up"></div></div>
                    <div id="dropdown-sticla-content" class="dropdown-content">
                        <ul type="none">
                        <li><a class="text">Termopan</a></li>
                        <li><a class="text">Tripan</a></li>
                        <li><a class="text">Sablata</a></li>
                        <li><a class="text">Anti-Efractie</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <div id="buton-feronerie" class="buton" onclick="expansiune_feronerie()">Feronerie<div id="arrow-up-feronerie" class="arrow-up"></div></div>
                    <div id="dropdown-feronerie-content" class="dropdown-content">
                        <ul type="none">
                        <li><a class="text">G.U</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <div id="buton-tehnici" class="buton" onclick="expansiune_tehnici()">Tehnici umbrire<div id="arrow-up-tehnici" class="arrow-up"></div></div>
                    <div id="dropdown-tehnici-content" class="dropdown-content">
                        <ul type="none">
                        <span><li><a class="text">Rulouri</a></li>
                        <li><a class="text">Rolete</a></li>
                        <li><a class="text">Jaluzele</a></li>
                        <li><a class="text">Obloane</a></li></span>
                        <span><li><a class="text">Plase Insecte</a></li></span>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="buton-s">Contact</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS I used is this one right here:

```
html, body{
            margin:0px;
            padding:0px;
            max-width: 100%;
        }
        .wrapper {
            height: 110px;
            width: 100%;
            max-width: 10000px;
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        }
        .logo {
            float: left;
            margin-top: 10px;
            margin-left: 5px;
            width: 200px;
            height: 100px;
        }
        .meniu {
            float: right;
            width: auto;
        }
        .buton-meniu {
            display: block;
            cursor: pointer;
            width: 35px;
            margin-right: 30px;
            margin-top: 40px;
        }
        .bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {
            width: 35px;
            height: 5px;
            background-color: #ffff;
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
            margin: 6px 0;
            transition: 0.4s;
        }
        .change .bar1 {
            -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
            transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
        }
        .change .bar2 {
            opacity: 0;
        }
        .change .bar3 {
            -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
            transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
        }
        .dropdown-meniu {
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
        }
        .dropdown-meniu-content {
            top: 110px;
            position: fixed;
            background-color: #ffff;
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
            width: 30%;
            max-width: 10000px;
            height: 100%;
            min-height: 1000px;
            box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
            z-index: 1;
            overflow: auto;
            -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
            right: 0;
            transform: translateX(100%);
            transition: transform 0.5s ease;
        }
        .show {
            transform: translateX(0%);
        }
        .dropdown {
            cursor: pointer;
            font-family: Oswald;
            color: #00a60c;
            margin-top: 15px;
            margin-left: 5px;
            font-size: 1.5em;
        }
        .dropdown-content {
            height: 0px;
            overflow: hidden;
            transition: height 0.5s;
            font-family: Ubuntu;
            color: #00a60c;
            font-size: 0.8em;
        }
        #dropdown-usi-content span {
            float: left;
        }
        #dropdown-tehnici-content span {
            float: left;
        }
        .buton {
            cursor: pointer;
            font-family: Oswald;
            color: #00a60c;
            margin-top: 15px;
            margin-left: 15px;
            font-size: 1.5em;
        }
        .buton-s {
            cursor: pointer;
            font-family: Oswald;
            color: #00a60c;
            margin-top: 15px;
            margin-left: 15px;
            font-size: 1.7em;
        }
        .expand {
            height: 120px;
        }
        #arrow-up-tehnici {
            margin-right: 20px;
        }
        .arrow-up {
            width: 0; 
            height: 0; 
            border-left: 10px solid transparent;
            border-right: 10px solid transparent;
            border-bottom: 10px solid #00a60c;
            float: right;
            margin-right: 20px;
            margin-top: 12px;
            transform: rotate(0deg);
            transition: transform 0.5s;
        }
        .rotate {
            transform: rotate(180deg);
        }
        .text {
            margin-top: 0px;
        }
        @media screen and ( max-width: 751px ) {
            .dropdown-meniu-content {
                width: 100%;
                max-width: 7510px;
                top: 110px;
            }
        }
```

This is my very sloppy JavaScript.If you have any suggestions to simplify it and such, i'd be verry happy, especially since the code for the expansion of the menu elements is very sloppy in my point of view and I think I can simplify it but I can't figure out how to do so.

```
if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer' ||  !!(navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident/) || navigator.userAgent.match(/rv:11/)) || (typeof $.browser !== "undefined" && $.browser.msie == 1))
{
    alert("Va rugam sa folositi alt browser cu site-ul nostru!Internet Explorer este un browser cu probleme de securitate, iar noi nu il suportam, asa ca veti fi redirectionati.Va multumim!");
    window.location.replace("http://www.google.com");
}
var button = document.querySelector('#buton-meniu');
var content = document.querySelector('#dropdown-meniu-content');

button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.currentTarget.classList.toggle('change');
    content.classList.toggle('show');
}, true)

document.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (content.classList.contains('show')) {
        content.classList.remove('show');
        button.classList.remove('change');
    }
})

content.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
})
function expansiune_ferestre() {
    document.getElementById("dropdown-ferestre-content").classList.toggle("expand");
    document.getElementById("arrow-up-ferestre").classList.toggle("rotate");
}
function expansiune_usi() {
    document.getElementById("dropdown-usi-content").classList.toggle("expand");
    document.getElementById("arrow-up-usi").classList.toggle("rotate");
}
function expansiune_sticla() {
    document.getElementById("dropdown-sticla-content").classList.toggle("expand");
    document.getElementById("arrow-up-sticla").classList.toggle("rotate");
}
function expansiune_feronerie() {
    document.getElementById("dropdown-feronerie-content").classList.toggle("expand");
    document.getElementById("arrow-up-feronerie").classList.toggle("rotate");
}
function expansiune_tehnici() {
    document.getElementById("dropdown-tehnici-content").classList.toggle("expand");
    document.getElementById("arrow-up-tehnici").classList.toggle("rotate");
}
```

This is a JSFiddle for the code: https://jsfiddle.net/TakeDown/k3zywqqj/ .

Thank you for your time and I hope my question(s)(if you count the request to look over the javascript code) aren't/isn't too silly!

Comment: This probably belongs on the [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) SE site.

Comment: the jsfiddle is wrong.

Comment: i have updated it @bharat-gupta

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is more suited for code review.

Comment: @TakeDown you have a `min-height` on the class "dropdown-meniu-content". Remove it and the scroll works just fine.

Comment: Nope. If you want, i can give you a link to the site, as it is live.But it is in Romanian, if you don't mind